# OpenBox tiling keybindings

Tags: openbox, tiling-wm

I'm running OpenBox on a Debian 10 Buster system and I would like to configure it to behave like a tiling window manager. I know OpenBox is a stacking window manager but since it is pretty well customizable I am sure we can make up something. However I don't how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't expect OpenBox to behave like a tiling window manager, because as you said, it's a stacking window manager. However you can tweak it with some scripts to add some tiling WM functionalities.

Have a look at `pytyle` ([manual](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=78666) and [GitHub page](https://github.com/BurntSushi/pytyle3)), [`zentile`](https://github.com/blrsn/zentile) and [`Openbox-tiling`](https://github.com/capn-damo/Openbox-tiling). I never tried the last one but the first two scripts are working like a charm on my system. `zentile` is easier to install by the way:  just download the executable, make it executable on your system and add the line `path_to_zentile/zentile_linx_amd64 &` in your `~/.config/openbox/autostart` file. You can change the keybindings in your `~/.config/openbox/zentile/conf.toml` file.

Comment: Although configuring your own OpenBox is great (and that's what I recommend), there are Linux distributions that provide pre-configured versions of OpenBox: [Viperr](https://viperr.org) based on Fedora has `pytyle` by default, [Mabox](https://maboxlinux.org/) based on Manjaro, [BunsenLabs](https://www.bunsenlabs.org/) based on Debian...

Comment: zentil works very well! Thank for the anwser, I'll have a look at those distros.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually sort of possible using Openbox. In this setup (put in rc.xml) I have Alt+keypad move the active window to the cardinal positions, and Alt+KP5 to maximize it, and Alt+KP0 to minimize the window:

```
<!-- Keybindings for tiling -->
<keybind key="A-KP_5">
  <action name="ToggleMaximize"/>
</keybind>
<keybind key="A-KP_0">
  <action name="Iconify"/>
</keybind>
<keybind key="A-KP_4">
  <action name="Unmaximize"/>
  <action name="MoveResizeTo">
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>50%</width>
    <height>100%</height>
  </action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="A-KP_6">
  <action name="Unmaximize"/>
  <action name="MoveResizeTo">
    <x>-0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>50%</width>
    <height>100%</height>
  </action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="A-KP_8">
  <action name="Unmaximize"/>
  <action name="MoveResizeTo">
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>100%</width>
    <height>50%</height>
  </action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="A-KP_2">
  <action name="Unmaximize"/>
  <action name="MoveResizeTo">
    <x>0</x>
    <y>-0</y>
    <width>100%</width>
    <height>50%</height>
  </action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="A-KP_7">
  <action name="Unmaximize"/>
  <action name="MoveResizeTo">
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>50%</width>
    <height>50%</height>
  </action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="A-KP_9">
  <action name="Unmaximize"/>
  <action name="MoveResizeTo">
    <x>-0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>50%</width>
    <height>50%</height>
  </action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="A-KP_1">
  <action name="Unmaximize"/>
  <action name="MoveResizeTo">
    <x>0</x>
    <y>-0</y>
    <width>50%</width>
    <height>50%</height>
  </action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="A-KP_3">
  <action name="Unmaximize"/>
  <action name="MoveResizeTo">
    <x>-0</x>
    <y>-0</y>
    <width>50%</width>
    <height>50%</height>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

References and further reading:

There's more in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/uriel1998/f181937ccd3fc56a8490b0b646d565c4), which is from [a post](https://ideatrash.net/2019/06/organizing-and-tiling-your-windows-on-openbox-using-only-openbox.html) I wrote (which also talks about some other similar keybinds), which was inspired by a post by [Thomas Hunter](https://thomashunter.name/posts/2019-01-27-treating-openbox-like-a-tiling-windowmanager).

Comment: The post on ideatrash.net that you link to appears to be your own. Please be aware that not disclosing your affiliation is considered spam. Please read:: [How to not be a spammer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).

Comment: @RobertColumbia not when the link is just an afterthought and the relevant information is included here! You could suggest an edit adding a changing "this post" to "my post" if you want, but given that all the information is here, and Steven isn't suggesting his own tool, simply linking to a post he wrote which has more information, I see no issue at all.

Comment: My apologies; I was trying to avoid seeming like I was bragging.  Thank you @terdon for the edit to fix my mistake.